# How to rename columns based on the names of the previous column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with columns generated from scraping the web for info in which several columns get the same name, e.g.

```
plaintiff,attorney,defendant,attorney 
Mr. Litigious, Laywer A,Big Company,Lawyer B
```

See how the `attorney`columns have the same name? I can make them unique with `janitor::clean_names` but that is not very useful: I would like to have the `attorney`columns renamed based on the previous columns, as in the following example:

```
plaintiff,attorney_plaintiff,defendant,attorney_defendant
Mr. Litigious, Laywer A,Big Company,Lawyer B
```

The purpose is to identify who is representing whom in the cases I am scraping.

After much searching, I can't figure out what the proper way of doing such a thing would look like. I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64258113/renaming-the-columns-in-pd-dataframe-based-on-the-adjacent-column-name) in Python, but I am wondering whether this can be achieved using R.

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this :

```
cols <- names(df)
inds <- which(duplicated(cols) | duplicated(cols, fromLast = TRUE))
names(df)[inds] <- paste( cols[inds], cols[inds - 1],sep = '_')
df

#      plaintiff attorney_plaintiff   defendant attorney_defendant
#1 Mr. Litigious           Laywer A Big Company           Lawyer B

names(df)
#[1] "plaintiff"  "attorney_plaintiff" "defendant"     "attorney_defendant"
```